# Problem with static library for atmega328

Tags: c, atmega

I have started to move some of my atmega code into a static library for easier use in the future. This has some issues with ussing the library. I have compiled and linked againsed it, and it runs. The problem is the USART function that takes an array as input seems to just send noise to my com port. It worked fine before i put the code in a static lib.

Makefile library

```
## General Flags
PROJECT = june
MCU = atmega328p
TARGET = libJune.a
CC = avr-g++
F_CPU   :=  1200000LL

## Options common to compile, link and 
assembly rules
COMMON = -fpack-struct -fshort-enums - 
funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields - 
mmcu=$(MCU) -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)

## Compile options common for all C 
compilation units.
CFLAGS = $(COMMON)
CFLAGS += -Wall -Os -MD -MP -MT -MF
#CFLAGS += -MD -MP -MT $(*F).o -MF 
dep/$(@F) 

## Objects that must be built in order 
to link
OBJECTS := adc.o pwm.o message.o 
messagehandler.o 
messagetranslationsenter.o usart.o

## Build
all: $(TARGET)

## Compile
adc.o: adc.cpp
$(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

pwm.o: pwm.cpp
$(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

message.o: message.cpp
$(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

messagehandler.o: messagehandler.cpp
$(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

messagetranslationsenter.o: 
messagetranslationsenter.cpp
$(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

usart.o: usart.cpp
$(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

## Archive into a library file (.a)
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
avr-ar -r $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

## Clean target
.PHONY: clean
clean:
-rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET) #dep/*
```

Makefile program

```
# the GNU make program
#

VERSION      := 0.1
PROGRAM_NAME := heater$(VERSION)


# Chip and programmer 
DEVICE_PROGRAMMER := usbtiny
CPU_AVRDUDE := m328p

MCU     := atmega328p
F_CPU       :=  1200000LL


LIB_PATH    := $(JUNE_ROOT)/avr
LIBS        := -lJune -lm
INCLUDES    := -I$(JUNE_ROOT)/avr

# FLAGS
CF      := -c -Os -fpack-struct - fshort-enums -funsigned-char -funsigned- bitfields -mmcu=$(MCU) -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU) 
$(INCLUDES)
LF      := -Os -MD -MP -mmcu=$(MCU) -MT -static -L$(LIB_PATH) $(LIBS)
# TOOLS
CC          := avr-g++
avrdude     ?= avrdude


OBJECTS = main.o


all: $(PROGRAM_NAME)

main.o: main.cpp
$(CC) $(CF) -c $<

$(PROGRAM_NAME): $(OBJECTS)
$(MAKE) -C $(JUNE_ROOT)/avr
$(CC) -o $(PROGRAM_NAME) $(OBJECTS) 
$(LF)


$(PROGRAM_NAME).hex: $(PROGRAM_NAME)
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom 
$(PROGRAM_NAME) $(PROGRAM_NAME).hex

.PHONY: flash
flash: programmedDevice


clean:
    -rm -f *.o *.hex *.elf 
programmedDevice_*.time

programmedDevice:  $(PROGRAM_NAME).hex
$(avrdude) -c $(DEVICE_PROGRAMMER) -p 
$(CPU_AVRDUDE) -v -U 
flash:w:$(PROGRAM_NAME).hex
touch programmedDevice_$(CPU_GCC).time

$(PROGRAM_NAME)_$(CPU_GCC).hex: 
$(Ofiles)
$(CC) $(LF) -o 
$(PROGRAM_NAME)_$(CPU_GCC).elf 
$(Ofiles)
$(avr_objcopy) -j .text -j .data -O 
ihex  $(PROGRAM_NAME)_$(CPU_GCC).elf  
$(PROGRAM_NAME)_$(CPU_GCC).hex

clean:
    -rm -f *.o *.hex *.elf 
programmedDevice_*.time
$(MAKE) -C $(JUNE_ROOT)/avr  clean

dumpchip_srec: 
    $(avrdude) -c $(DEVICE_PROGRAMMER) 
-p $(CPU_AVRDUDE) -U 
lfuse:r:lfuse_$(CPU_GCC).hex:i -U 
hfuse:r:hfuse_$(CPU_GCC).hex:i -U 
efuse:r:efuse_$(CPU_GCC).hex:i -U 
eeprom:r:eeprom_$(CPU_GCC).hex:i -U 
flash:r:flash_$(CPU_GCC).hex:i -U 
lock:r:lock_$(CPU_GCC).hex:i -U 
signature:r:sig_$(CPU_GCC).hex:i 

dumpchip: 
$(avrdude) -c $(DEVICE_PROGRAMMER) -p 
$(CPU_AVRDUDE) -U 
lfuse:r:lfuse_$(CPU_GCC).bin:r -U 
hfuse:r:hfuse_$(CPU_GCC).bin:r -U 
eeprom:r:eeprom_$(CPU_GCC).bin:r -U 
flash:r:flash_$(CPU_GCC).bin:r -U 
lock:r:lock_$(CPU_GCC).bin:r -U 
signature:r:sig_$(CPU_GCC).bin:r -U 
efuse:r:efuse_$(CPU_GCC).bin:r 

check:
    $(avrdude) -v -c 
$(DEVICE_PROGRAMMER) -p $(CPU_AVRDUDE)
```

This is the part of the test software, that calls the usart function from the static library, but I can only read noise from the com port it sends data too.

```
while(true)
{
    //
    USART_putstring("Test");
    _delay_ms(5000);
}
```

I think there is a compiler flag missing that i can not find. Everything is running fine if I add the usart files to the program and compile it. The problem is when the files are put in a static library.

Edit:

it works when i put the define F_CPU in the source file, instead of -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU) from the Makefile

Comment: This does not include the code that you say has problems ... are you sure you still initialize the port correctly? Also you should prune/clean your `Makefile`, you're using C-specific machinery (such as `CFLAGS`) to build C++ which is super confusing.

Comment: Hi. Strange... in the last makefile you have two "clean" targets, which are both static rules. How can that work? Also some parts of the makefile are not correctly indented. Can you correct that and post your whole code? From what I see I see no problem regarding the .a file.

```

$(PROGRAM_NAME): $(OBJECTS)
$(MAKE) -C $(JUNE_ROOT)/avr
$(CC) -o $(PROGRAM_NAME) $(OBJECTS) 
```

Does not link a static library but the original object files...

Comment: It may be a good idea to double check connection baud rate in the software, that used to read data from port.

Comment: andi8086, it just make sure the library is up to date if the program is rebuild. In case I add some extra to the library.

Comment: unwind: I can add more code, but it works fine if i add the files to the program and compile it. I think it is just a compiler flag that are missing

Comment: By noise, do you mean diffrent chars than expected? Check bauds in USART initalization function and compare it with software that you are reading. If you are using, some USART/USB dongle converter you should check GND connections.